# PowerShell Copy-Item not copying all files

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have a strange issue with the Copy-Item in PowerShell. Below you see two almost identical lines of code, only the source and destination is different.

```
Copy-Item "A:\*" -Destination "B:\" -Recurse -Force -Verbose -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinu
Start-Sleep 3
Copy-Item "B:\*" -Destination "D:\" -Recurse -Force -Verbose -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinu
```

These lines are a part of a script. It first notes the date and creates a log file and then it clears the B and D drive. After that, it starts copying. The first one, the Copy-Item A:\ to B:\ works, it copies everything.

When PowerShell gets to the second one, it only copies a few folders and just skips over the remaining folders. It doesn't throw me an error or anything.

When I manually execute the second line, it works, but not when it's in a script.

What is wrong here?

Comment: I'd use robocopy for this: `ROBOCOPY /MIR <Source> <Target>` -- the `MIR` (mirror) switch will both copy source to target and delete anything in target that isn't present in source. Leaving target as a mirror copy of source.

Comment: I'm currently copying the files with robocopy. Will let you know how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) for this, it's included in all modern versions of windows and is very powerful and can complete pretty much any copy function you want.

```
ROBOCOPY /MIR <Source> <Target>
```

`/MIR` is the mirror switch. It will both copy source to target and delete anything in target that isn't present in source. Leaving target as a mirror copy of source.

You might also want to look into the `/MT` multi-thread switch to speed things up if the directories contain a large number of files.

Comment: Thanks @James C. You provided the answer. I used: "Robocopy /MIR A:\ B:\ /e /copyall /w:1 /r:1" and it worked marvelously! It copied everything. Except the files that are opened by processes, but I don't mind that.